# openerp-server database issue

Tags: python, postgresql

[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)
[python](/questions/tagged/python)

I need some help fixing some issues with a postgresql database I use for openerp-server. I looked everywhere to find an answer but I couldn't get any reposes from OpenERP community. Hope some of you postgresql professionals could show me some indications on fixing my broken db.

Here are the errors I encountered starting openerp-server in debug mode:

```
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">postgres@nodesoft-dev:~$ cd
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">postgres@nodesoft-dev:/usr/lib/python2.5/site-   packages/openerp-server$ × 79465
[tag:python]/usr/bin/python2.5 ./openerp-server.py -dnodesoft --update=all
--stop-after-init --log-level=debug
--addons-path=/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,067]
DEBUGsycopg2:installed. Logging using Python logging module</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,067]
INFO:server:version - 5.0.6</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,067]
INFO:server:addons_path -
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,067]
INFO:server:database hostname - localhost</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,067]
INFO:server:database port - 5432</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,071]
INFO:server:database user - postgres</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,071]
INFObjects:initialising distributed objects services</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,239]
INFO:dbpool:Connecting to nodesoft</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,379]
INFO:init:module base: loading objects</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,379]
INFO:init:module base: registering objects</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:01,491]
INFO:init:module base: creating or updating database tables</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251] DEBUG:sql:bad
query: alter table &quot;ir_model_data&quot; add constraint
&quot;ir_model_data_module_name_uniq&quot; unique(name, module)</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251]
DEBUG:sql:[01]: could not create unique index
&quot;ir_model_data_module_name_uniq&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251]
DEBUG:sql:[02]: DETAIL: Table contains duplicated values.</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251]
WARNINGrm:[01]: unable to add 'unique(name, module)' constraint on
table ir_model_data !</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251]
WARNINGrm:[02]: If you want to have it, you should update the records
and execute manually:</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:08,251]
WARNINGrm:[03]: ALTER table ir_model_data ADD CONSTRAINT
ir_model_data_module_name_uniq unique(name, module)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:02:27,611]
DEBUGrm:creating new column datas of table ir_attachment</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:06,524]
INFO:init:module base: loading base_data.xml</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:07,488]
INFO:init:module base: loading base_menu.xml</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:07,828]
INFO:init:module base: loading security/base_security.xml</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,496] DEBUG:sql:bad
query: update &quot;res_users&quot; set
&quot;menu_id&quot;=1,&quot;address_id&quot;=1,&quot;action_id&quot;=1,&quot;company_
id&quot;=1,&quot;signature&quot;=E'Administrator',write_uid=1,wri
te_date=now() where id in (1)</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,496] × 6848
[tag:postgresql]DEBUG:sql:[01]: insert or update on table &quot;res_users&quot;
violates foreign key constraint &quot;res_users_address_id_fkey&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,496]
DEBUG:sql:[02]: DETAIL: Key (address_id)=(1) is not present in table
&quot;res_partner_address&quot;.</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">sh: bzr: command not found</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">sh: lsb_release: command not found</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[01]:</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[02]: Environment Information :</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[03]: System :
Linux-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-5.0.4</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[04]: OS Name : posix</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[05]: Operating System Release : 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[06]: Operating System Version : #1 SMP Wed Jan 13
00:12:41 UTC 2010</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620] 
ERROR:init:[07]: Operating System Architecture : 64bit</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[08]: Operating System Locale : en_US.ISO8859-1</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,620]
ERROR:init:[09]: Python Version : 2.5.2</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[10]: OpenERP-Server Version : 5.0.6</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[11]: Last revision No. &amp; ID :</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[12]: &lt;record id=&quot;base.user_root&quot;
model=&quot;res.users&quot;&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[13]: &lt;field name=&quot;signature&quot;&gt;Administrator&lt;/field&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[14]: &lt;field name=&quot;address_id&quot;

ref=&quot;main_address&quot;/&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[15]: &lt;field name=&quot;company_id&quot;
ref=&quot;main_company&quot;/&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[16]: &lt;field name=&quot;action_id&quot;
ref=&quot;action_menu_admin&quot;/&gt;</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[17]: &lt;field name=&quot;menu_id&quot;
ref=&quot;action_menu_admin&quot;/&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">[2011-10-29 18:03:08,624]
ERROR:init:[18]: &lt;/record&gt;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Traceback (most recent call last):</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File &quot;./openerp-server.py&quot;,
line 111, in &lt;module&gt;</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">pooler.get_db_and_pool(db,
update_module=tools.config['init'] or tools.config['update'])</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/pooler.py&quot;,
line 40, in get_db_and_pool</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">addons.load_modules(db, force_demo,
status, update_module)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/__init__.py&quot;,
line 687, in load_modules</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">has_updates = load_module_graph(cr,
graph, status, perform_checks=(not update_module), report=report)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/__init__.py&quot;,
line 618, in load_module_graph</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">tools.convert_xml_import(cr, m, fp,
idref, mode=mode, **kwargs)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/tools/convert.py&quot;,
line 885, in convert_xml_import</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">obj.parse(xmlstr)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/tools/convert.py&quot;,
line 779, in parse</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">self._tags[rec.nodeName](self.cr, rec,
n)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/tools/convert.py&quot;,
line 747, in _tag_record</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">id =
self.pool.get('ir.model.data')._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model,
self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node),
noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode )</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py&quot;,
line 474, in _update</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">model_obj.write(cr, uid, [res_id],
values)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/base/res/res_user.py&quot;,
line 185, in write</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">res = super(users, self).write(cr, uid,
ids, values, *args, **argv)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/osv/orm.py&quot;,
line 2458, in write</P>

<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">'where id in ('+ids_str+')', upd1)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/sql_db.py&quot;,
line 76, in wrapper</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">return f(self, *args, **kwargs)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">File
&quot;/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/sql_db.py&quot;,
line 120, in execute</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">res = self._obj.execute(query, params)</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">psycopg2.IntegrityError: insert or
update on table &quot;res_users&quot; violates foreign key constraint

&quot;res_users_address_id_fkey&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">DETAIL: Key (address_id)=(1) is not
present in table &quot;res_partner_address&quot; 
</P>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openerp is trying to update the 'Administrator' address_id and it doesn't seems to exists.
You can add it with dummy values with a command like this:

```
INSERT INTO res_partner_address VALUES (1, 1, '2011-11-02 14:50:55.607533', '2011-11-03    12:48:03.231399', 1, 5, '', NULL, '', '', true, 1, '', '', '', NULL, NULL, 67, NULL, 2, 'default', '');
```

You must review this sql to point to the correct registers, for example the 6th field (5), points to the partner_id (it must exists), 18th (67) is the country_id or 20th (2) is the state_id.

After insert this record, try again to launch the server...

Comment: Hi Antonio. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't work as that partner_id doesn't exist. I've tried to insert that value into partner_id but that won't work also Here's what I did: insert into res_partner_address (partner_id) VALUES ('1'); ERROR:  insert or update on table "res_partner_address" violates foreign key constraint "res_partner_address_partner_id_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (partner_id)=(1) is not present in table "res_partner".

Comment: You need to create the res_partner record also. Something like this:

Comment: INSERT INTO res_partner VALUES (1, 1, '2011-11-07 14:50:55.607533', '2011-11-07 12:46:40.962586', 1, NULL, NULL, true, NULL, 'en_UK', false, NULL, NULL, 'My Company', ' ', NULL, NULL, false, NULL, '', NULL, true, NULL, NULL, NULL, true, 'no-message', 'no-message', NULL, 'no-message', 'no-message', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, true, 0, NULL, NULL);